# Python tkinter -'name is not defined'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is a madlibs game, I everything works fine, until I clicked the 'submit' button, which prompted an error 'NameError: name 'new_Window_1_lbResult' is not defined'. The code is a quite long and repetitive, so I have highlighted the code with the problem.

```
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()
window.title('MadLibs game')

window.geometry('500x150')

input_words=list()

'''
this is the code with problem 
'''

def Submit():
    new_Window_1_lbResult['text']='say ' + input_words[5] + ', the photographer said as the camera flashed! ' + input_words[4] + ' and I had gone to ' + input_words[5] +' to get our photos taken on my birthday. The first photo we really wanted was a picture of us dressed as ' + input_words[0] + ' pretending to be a ' + input_words[1] + '. when we saw the second photo, it was exactly what I wanted. We both looked like ' + input_words[3] + ' wearing ' + input_words[2] + ' and ' + input_words[6] + ' --exactly what I had in mind'
    
                                

    
def newWindow1():
    new_Window_1=tk.Toplevel()
    new_Window_1.geometry('500x500')
    new_Window_1_Title=tk.Label(new_Window_1,text='Type in the words now!',fg='red')
    new_Window_1_Title.grid(row=0,columnspan=2,pady=5)
# create all labels for the inputs    
    new_Window_1_lbAnimals=tk.Label(new_Window_1,text='enter a animal name:')
    new_Window_1_lbProfession=tk.Label(new_Window_1,text='enter a profession name:')
    new_Window_1_lbCloth=tk.Label(new_Window_1,text='enter a piece of cloth name:')
    new_Window_1_lbThings=tk.Label(new_Window_1,text='enter a thing name:')
    new_Window_1_lbName=tk.Label(new_Window_1,text='enter a name:')
    new_Window_1_lbPlace=tk.Label(new_Window_1,text='enter a place name:')
    new_Window_1_lbVerb=tk.Label(new_Window_1,text='enter a verb in ing form:')
    new_Window_1_lbFood=tk.Label(new_Window_1,text='enter a food name:')

    new_Window_1_lbAnimals.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_lbProfession.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_lbCloth.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_lbThings.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_lbName.grid(row=5,column=0,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_lbPlace.grid(row=6,column=0,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_lbVerb.grid(row=7,column=0,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_lbFood.grid(row=8,column=0,sticky='ew')

#create all entry for the inputs
    new_Window_1_entAnimals=tk.Entry(new_Window_1)
    new_Window_1_entProfession=tk.Entry(new_Window_1)
    new_Window_1_entCloth=tk.Entry(new_Window_1)
    new_Window_1_entThings=tk.Entry(new_Window_1)
    new_Window_1_entName=tk.Entry(new_Window_1)
    new_Window_1_entPlace=tk.Entry(new_Window_1)
    new_Window_1_entVerb=tk.Entry(new_Window_1)
    new_Window_1_entFood=tk.Entry(new_Window_1)

    new_Window_1_entAnimals.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_entProfession.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_entCloth.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_entThings.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_entName.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_entPlace.grid(row=6,column=1,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_entVerb.grid(row=7,column=1,sticky='ew')
    new_Window_1_entFood.grid(row=8,column=1,sticky='ew')
    


#put all entry inputs inside a list
    input_words.append(new_Window_1_entAnimals.get())
    input_words.append(new_Window_1_entProfession.get())
    input_words.append(new_Window_1_entCloth.get())
    input_words.append(new_Window_1_entThings.get())
    input_words.append(new_Window_1_entName.get())
    input_words.append(new_Window_1_entPlace.get())
    input_words.append(new_Window_1_entVerb.get())
    input_words.append(new_Window_1_entFood.get())

'''
this code call the command from above, it should be fine. 
'''

#create buttons for submit
    new_Window_1_butSubmit=tk.Button(new_Window_1,text='submit',command=Submit)
    new_Window_1_butSubmit.grid(row=9,columnspan=2,pady=5)

# create final result
    new_Window_1_lbResult=tk.Label(new_Window_1,text='ggg')
    new_Window_1_lbResult.grid(row=10,columnspan=2)

    
window1_label=tk.Label(text=
                       """You are now playing a MadLibs game,click the button below to start!"""
                       ,pady=5).pack()
window1_button=tk.Button(text='Click to start!!!', command=newWindow1 ).pack()
```

this is the first window, it works fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2CpE.png)

this is the second window, it works fine too
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVUke.png)

but as soon as I press 'submit' button, it shows the following error

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Brian Tse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Python\Project\MadLibs game.py", line 11, in Submit
    new_Window_1_lbResult['text']='say ' + input_words[5] + ', the photographer said as the camera flashed! ' + input_words[4] + ' and I had gone to ' + input_words[5] +' to get our photos taken on my birthday. The first photo we really wanted was a picture of us dressed as ' + input_words[0] + ' pretending to be a ' + input_words[1] + '. when we saw the second photo, it was exactly what I wanted. We both looked like ' + input_words[3] + ' wearing ' + input_words[2] + ' and ' + input_words[6] + ' --exactly what I had in mind'
NameError: name 'new_Window_1_lbResult' is not defined
```

can anyone explain why? Also, is there any way to shorten this code or improve it? Because I feel like this code is too repetitive.

Comment: `new_Window_1_lbResult` is local to `newWindow1`; it's not available to your `Submit` function.

Comment: Add `global new_Window_1_lbResult` at the start of your `newWindow1` function

Comment: It would probably be better to define `Submit` *inside* `newWindow1`, rather than making the variable global, although that advice is subject to change depending on where else the variable may be needed.

Comment: @chepner Defining functions inside other function is bad practise. I know that global variables are also considered bad practise by some people but as long as you remember the names of the global variables you are going to be fine.

Comment: @TheLizzard Why? Closures are *incredibly* useful.

Comment: @chepner It's hard to read. Also just as a note, some people take it too far. I have seen a function defined inside a function that is defined inside another function that is in a class that is inside another function. Global variables are also easier to document at the start of the script in a comment

Comment: Good thing I'm not suggesting such excessive nesting. Defining `Submit` local avoids *two* global variables (`Submit` itself and `new_Window_1_lbResult`) by letting `Submit` close over the local variable `new_Window_1_lbResult`). And to be clear, nothing in the code shown indicates where else `new_Window_1_lbResult` will be used, so I'm not saying "Absolutely don't use a global variable", because it may well be necessary (or at least, there's not enough context to suggest an appropriate alternative).

Comment: @TheLizzard If `Submit()` is only used by `newWindow1()`, putting it inside `newWindow1()` is better than using global variables.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Now the MadLibs game can run smoothly now.

Comment: @acw1668 If a function that simple is going to only be used in that piece of code then it would be better to just not have that function and use a `lambda` (using the `.config` method). Also why do people have a fear of global variables? As long as you keep track of the global variables, you should never encounter a problem.

Comment: @chepner Why not define the whole code in a function? That way you will have only 1 global variable? As long as you keep track of the global variables, you should never encounter a problem. Global variables are easier to document, just use a single multiline comment at the start of the file that describes all of them. Documenting nested function is difficult and you can end up with identical functions defined in different places.

Comment: You wouldn't document the nested function any more than you would any of the other local variables. It's an implementation detail of the function is occurs in, not part any interface.

Comment: @chepner And you can end up defining the same function over and over again if you revisit the project in the future. Having a global function is better because you can documented and reuse it later. Also why do people hate global variables?

Comment: @TheLizzard For OP case, not only the label need to be referenced, those `Entry` widgets are also be referenced in order to get their values to construct the message.  So I still think using nested function is better than using global variables.  And I am not fear to use global variables, I just think nested function is better than global variables in this case.

Comment: @acw1668 Why don't you pass it in as arguments? That will surely make it easier to document and it will be easier to reuse.

Comment: @TheLizzard Please stop objecting to things that aren't going to happen. This isn't a function that's going to be called repeatedly; it's a one-time function to create the interface.